# Проблема со списком ForeignKey в Django ModelForm

Tags: django

У меня есть список сотрудников.

models.py:

```
class NumberOfMealsEaten(models.Model):
month = models.ForeignKey(Months, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
staff = models.ForeignKey(Staffs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
maelseaten = models.IntegerField("Number of meals eaten", validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.staff)
```

Для этих сотрудников плата за питание рассчитывается каждый месяц в зависимости от того, сколько блюд съел каждый сотрудник.

Во-первых, в начале я хочу выбрать "название соответствующего месяца" только один раз. Затем я хочу, чтобы имена сотрудников из Foreignkey автоматически указывались как "текст" в шаблоне, а не в виде раскрывающегося меню. Поэтому я просто хочу, чтобы поле "maelseaten" было заполнено для персонала.

В качестве примера список будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: Пример Списка]

Другими словами, эта форма добавит в базу данных количество приемов пищи для каждого сотрудника за выбранный месяц.

Заранее благодарю вас за внимание и помощь.

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @ZaArs Проблема в том что я не могу создать это :)

Comment: сделайте кастомную форму с формсетом, где месяц - одна форма, а для сотрудников  -формсет из инлайнов. сохранять в вручную после валидации